# AIDL implementation on Custom Object in separate module

Tags: android, parcelable, aidl

I have a custom Employee object in one module which doesn't implement Parcelable(module doesn't allow android components)

How can i implement AIDL in separate android module which returns Employee object in one of the methods?

One way i can achieve this is my extending parent object but while creating constructor with Parcel object input how can i call super method??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't say this is perfect solution but just a small work around,

create a class in aidl module and extend Employee class and implement parcelable. Implement aidl using this new class